# How do I bind a dynamically created asp textbox to a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox generated by parsing an xml file.

```
 TextBox tb = new TextBox;
 tb.ID = "MYDATA"
 Parent.Controls.Add(tb);
```

I then read another Xml file for the data to populate the created TextBox.  I have been trying all sorts of databinging and setting the text property to a dataset, but cannot figure it out.  If I set the text property at creation to say:

```
MyDataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].["MYDATA"].ToString();
```

I get an error because the dataset hasn't been created and wont be until the form has been created.  Am I going about this wrong?  Can't I someway specify that the data to fill the textbox is coming from the dataset without already creating it?

Comment: Can you post any of the code for your UI and what you are trying to do to add these controls etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're populating the `DataSet` in the same method that creates the `TextBox`, you should be able to do this:

```
tb.Text = MyDataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].["MYDATA"].ToString();
```

If you're populating the `DataSet` in another method after the `TextBox` has been created, you can use the `FindControl` method to search the parent container of the `TextBox`:

```
TextBox tb = Panel1.FindControl("MYDATA") as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    tb.Text = MyDataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].["MYDATA"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to set the Text property at create time by using the DataBinder.Eval method?

Comment: That depends on whether the TextBox is enclosed in some kind of databound control.